# find all matrices that com-mute with the given matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

So I have this matrix and I need to find  all matrices that commute with the given matrix A.\begin{bmatrix}2 & 3\\-3 & 2\end{bmatrix}

I know how to get to the point where

$2a+3c = 2a-3b$

$2b+ 3d = 3a + 2b$

$-3a + 2c = 2c - 3d$

$-3b + 2d = 3c + 2d$

it's just the dot product

What confuses me is the rest of the solution. According to the book,

$c = -b$

$a = d$

$a = d$

$b = -c$

So the solution would be

\begin{bmatrix}a & b\\-b & a\end{bmatrix}

How do you get $c = -b,\ a = d,\ a = d,\ b = -c$ and the matrix from the equations above? I think is something simple I might be missing.

Comment: in each of the four equations, cancel the evident repeat summands. Then cancel the commom factors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider a generic matrix
$$
X=\begin{bmatrix}
a & b \\
c & d
\end{bmatrix}
$$
If $A$ is your matrix, the condition $AX=XA$ translates into
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
2a+3c & 2b+3d \\
-3a+2c & -3b+2d
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
2a-3b & 3a+2b \\
2c-3d & 3c+2d
\end{bmatrix}
$$
By comparing coefficients,
$$
\begin{cases}
2a+3c=2a-3b \\[4px]
2b+3d=3a+2b \\[4px]
-3a+2c=2c-3d \\[4px]
-3b+2d=3c+2d
\end{cases}
$$
The first equation is $3c=-3b$, or $c=-b$. Similarly for the others, so we get
$$
\begin{cases}
c=-b \\[4px]
d=a \\[4px]
a=d \\[4px]
-b=c
\end{cases}
$$
that simplifies into $d=a$ and $c=-b$. There's no restriction on $a$ and $b$, so you get all matrices of the form
$$
X=\begin{bmatrix}
a & b \\
-b & a
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Comment: why is b in there twice and in place of c?

Comment: @KevinR. Because $c=-b$.

Comment: One more thing.  Are they interchangeable?  Could you place c in there instead of -b as a is in there twice since a = d, and d also = a?

Comment: @KevinR. The meaning is that the elements on the diagonal must be equal and the other two must be opposite of one another, however you call them.